# How do I write generic higher order component that inject generic props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, typescript-generics, higher-order-components

I am trying to create an hoc which infers query params from next router, however I am unable to use it properly when I have to chain my components.

```
type Params<Q extends string> = Record<Q, string>;

function withQueryParam<Q extends string, P extends Params<Q>>(
  queryParamName: Q
) {
  return (Component: NextPage<P>) => {
    const displayName = Component.displayName || Component.name || "Component";

    const ComponentWrapped = (props:Omit<P, keyof Params<Q>>) => {
      const router = useRouter();
      const queryParamValue = router.query[queryParamName];

      if (!queryParamValue) {
        return <p>{"Loading Params"}</p>;
      }

      if (typeof queryParamValue !== "string") {
        return <p>{"Params"}</p>;
      }

      return (
        <Component
          {...(props as P)}
          {...{ [queryParamName]: queryParamValue }}
        />
      );
    };

    ComponentWrapped.displayName = `withQueryParam(${displayName})`;
    return ComponentWrapped;
  };
}
```

Now I do have type inference, if I do as follows

```
const AppointmentPage = withQueryParam("teamId")(({teamId}) => {
  return <div></div>
});
```

but I am just unable to get query params of outer hoc, if I do some chaining as follows

```
//[ERROR]: teamId is not defined
const AppointmentPage = withQueryParam("teamId")(withQueryParam('appointmentId')(({appointmentId,teamId}) => {
  return <div></div>
}));
```

Comment: Why do you want to write a higher-order component instead of a simple hook function?

Comment: I want to create something that can ensure that any query param exists and is valid, so that I don't have to deal with the case of it being undefined in my main component. I am not sure how one can acheive that using a hook function, if you have any idea, do let me know. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: what is `NextPage` doing?